# Group name in database. Show only one group name UITableView row

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I use parse.com as my database and when I perform a `PFQuery` I get an array with everything that I need. Now, each `Item` has one group and I want to have the `group name` in one `UITableViewController` when the user clicks. I want to open another `UITableViewController` with the `Item`s in that `group`.

My array has three items like:

ITEM 1
GROUP A

ITEM 2
GROUP A

ITEM 3
GROUP A

Now, suppose that in my first `UITableView` I want to show only one cell with the label `GROUP A`, because the user doesn't have any `item`s in other `group`s. Instead, with the following code, I'm getting three cells labeled `GROUP A`, because I have 3 `item`s.

```
PFObject *o = _seriesArray[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = o[@"serie"];
```

Assuming I can show only one cell labeled `GROUP A`, when the user clicks `GROUP A`, then I want to show a new `UITableView` with the three `item`s. How can I achieve this?

My source data is:

```
"<ExerciciosPeso:j4HWUbQaX3:(null)> {\n    exercicio = \"<Exercicios:Iv2XB4EHSY>\";\n    peso = 50;\n    serie = \"Serie A\";\n    usuario = \"<PFUser:W9ifgHpbov>\";\n}",
"<ExerciciosPeso:F11VGC6Nq9:(null)> {\n    exercicio = \"<Exercicios:nmqArIngvR>\";\n    peso = 40;\n    serie = \"Serie A\";\n    usuario = \"<PFUser:W9ifgHpbov>\";\n}",
"<ExerciciosPeso:izxU3w0j7u:(null)> {\n    exercicio = \"<Exercicios:CXecX4DJiO>\";\n    peso = 30;\n    serie = \"Serie A\";\n    usuario = \"<PFUser:W9ifgHpbov>\";\n}",
"<ExerciciosPeso:9t2PdNojl6:(null)> {\n    exercicio = \"<Exercicios:6slVOQnj3y>\";\n    peso = 10;\n    serie = \"Serie A\";\n    usuario = \"<PFUser:W9ifgHpbov>\";\n}"
```

)

This is the query:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *exerciciosQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ExerciciosPeso"];
    [exerciciosQuery whereKey:@"usuario" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [exerciciosQuery includeKey:@"exercicio"];

    _seriesArray = [exerciciosQuery findObjects];

    return exerciciosQuery;
}
```

I have a class with some pointers to other classes. This query stores everything in the array.

UPDATE

```
NSArray *allInformation = _seriesArray;
NSLog(@"%@", allInformation);
NSArray *groups = [allInformation valueForKey:@"serie"];
NSLog(@"%@", groups);
NSSet *uniqueGroups = [NSSet setWithArray:groups];
NSLog(@"%@", uniqueGroups);
NSSortDescriptor *serieDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"serie" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[serieDescriptor];
NSArray *groupsForDisplay = [uniqueGroups sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSLog(@"%@", groupsForDisplay);
```

I get the following outline:

```
2013-12-16 12:00:13.954 IRON TRAINERS[15725:70b] (
"<ExerciciosPeso:j4HWUbQaX3:(null)> {\n    exercicio = \"<Exercicios:Iv2XB4EHSY>\";\n    peso =  50;\n    serie = \"Serie A\";\n    usuario = \"<PFUser:W9ifgHpbov>\";\n}",
"<ExerciciosPeso:F11VGC6Nq9:(null)> {\n    exercicio = \"<Exercicios:nmqArIngvR>\";\n    peso = 40;\n    serie = \"Serie A\";\n    usuario = \"<PFUser:W9ifgHpbov>\";\n}",
"<ExerciciosPeso:izxU3w0j7u:(null)> {\n    exercicio = \"<Exercicios:CXecX4DJiO>\";\n    peso = 30;\n    serie = \"Serie A\";\n    usuario = \"<PFUser:W9ifgHpbov>\";\n}",
"<ExerciciosPeso:9t2PdNojl6:(null)> {\n    exercicio = \"<Exercicios:6slVOQnj3y>\";\n    peso = 10;\n    serie = \"Serie A\";\n    usuario = \"<PFUser:W9ifgHpbov>\";\n}"
)
2013-12-16 12:00:13.955 IRON TRAINERS[15725:70b] (
"Serie A",
"Serie A",
"Serie A",
"Serie A"
)
2013-12-16 12:00:13.955 IRON TRAINERS[15725:70b] {(
"Serie A"
)}
2013-12-16 12:00:13.955 IRON TRAINERS[15725:70b] (
"Serie A"
)
```

This is my group, I want to show only one cell of the same group, so, from this array, as I only have items from the same group, I want to show one cell labeled "Serie A". I'm still not sure how to do that using the line `cell.textLabel.text = ...`.

Comment: could you show your array format is it in key:value format? e.g. item1:groupA

Comment: Yes, my array return objects with key values. I'll edit above and show the array, although it doesn't list all the keys I'll use, they are there inside objects and pointers.

Comment: @ferrojr can you post little bit of query here

Comment: @ferrojr i think you need to sort and create a unique array as "Wain" answered i think that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your array of source information you need to filter it to produce the distinct set of groups, then sort it for display.

```
NSArray *allInformation = ...;
NSArray *groups = [allInformation valueForKay:@"serie"];
NSSet *uniqueGroups = [NSSet setWithArray:groups];
NSArray *groupsForDisplay = [uniqueGroups sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:...];
```

you need to create the sort descriptor based on what order you want...

Then, when the user taps, you can get the group name and filter (using `NSPredicate`) the source information to find all of the items with that group.

Comment: Thanks, please see update above, I'm still not sure how to show one group in my tableview and open another tableview with the items in that group. Also, sice I already have the results that I need, I wouldn't need to perform another query, would I? Thanks.

Comment: No additional query would be required, it's just a matter of filtering and sorting to get the right info for each screen.

Comment: Have you logged each stage of the first uniquing and filtering process? Is that a paste of the actual code? I know it isn't a paste of the full log output...

Comment: Just edited for full outline and code. Seems like I'm getting just one string with the group, sorting is working I guess. Now how do I put that into cell.textLabel? Thanks.

Comment: In your table view data source methods you use `groupsForDisplay` and get the group name for the index path provided. `groupsForDisplay` is the source of data for your first table view, not `_seriesArray`...

Comment: this line `PFObject *o = groupsForDisplay[indexPath.row];`is crashing: 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]' the second line would be `cell.textLabel.text = o[@"serie"];`thanks.

Comment: I'm getting a crash: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x10b0c0cb0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key serie.' for line `NSArray *groupsForDisplay = [uniqueGroups sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];`

Comment: `groupsForDisplay` is an array of strings, not `PFObject`s. Did you take the time to understand what your code is now doing?